# Publicly Available Ngram Datasets

Tags: dataset

Do you know any datasets other then Google's Google Book n-gram dataset? Especially some datasets about scientific papers would be great.

Comment: Please see our [faq] concerning questions about datasets: "Questions about obtaining particular datasets are off-topic (they are too specialized)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not specifically n-gram data, there are large fixed corpora of web pages available from the Web as Corpus projects---it would be pretty simple to extract n-grams from them. You can download these corpora, after your request is verified, from:

http://wacky.sslmit.unibo.it/doku.php?id=download

You can also download Wikipedia and do something similar if you like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download